# What does the "re-review" mean?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

We have written a revised manuscript since the original version is received a decision of "major revision."
Since the status remained "reviewer assigned," we sent a mail with requesting clarification. 
The journal editor office replied that the section editor decided to seek re-review for our manuscript given the nature and extent of the revisions requested.

Does "re-review" mean the revision is pending for the original reviewers' comments, or that the section editor sought other reviewers to re-examine the revision for different opinions, or something else?

Comment: There will be differences from one journal to another. Possibly form one editor to another. Even possibly from one editor-author relationship to another. There is not necessarily going to be clear, rational, logical, consistent application of this term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be either, but it usually goes back to the reviewers that requested the major modifications. Whoever the editor sent it to, it means that it is being reviewed again in full.

Comment: Typically the only reason to send it to other reviewers is if one of the original reviewers refuses to review a second time.

Comment: @jakebeal, or are unavailable, or fail to return their second review on time, or ....

Comment: Absolutely agreed.  My experience as an editor, however, has been that refusal is the most common reason: "Let this horrible paper never darken my door again."

Comment: @jakebeal: Why would any reviewer suggest a revise and resubmit instead of outright reject if they never wanted to see it again? That's just crazy.

Comment: They recommend reject and say that if you disagree they want no part of it.